# Solving a system by graphing

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I solve a system by graphing?

Please use these numbers to give me an example.

Also, I'd prefer a tutorial in only text.

Numbers:

$$5x-3y=-9$$

and

$$x+3y=-9$$

What do I do to get the y-intercept formula of each?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

plugging $$x=-9-3y$$ in your first formula we get
$$5(-9-3y)-3y=-9$$
expanding
we obtain
$$-45-15y-3y=-9$$
can you finish?